# Mysql: LIKE CONCAT Replacement --> less performance heavy

Tags: mysql, string, performance, search, concatenation

So I have a SELECT Statement that is comparing the current column content from the table_1 column "table_1_content" with the content of another column (table_2_content) in table_2, whereas content in "table_2_content" can be found anywhere in "table_1_content":

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE `table_1_content` LIKE CONCAT('%', table_2_content, '%')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $select);
```

My problem is that LIKE CONCAT is pretty performance heavy.

**Is there another way to search through two columns from different tables, so that no full table scan is performed every time the query is executed?**

Comment: The `%` at the start of the `LIKE` predicate will preclude the use of an index.  You could consider looking into full text search.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen FTS won't help, either, because it can't get the match data from another table, it has to be a literal.

Answer (score 2):

The `LIKE` in total free text format (`%` at the start and at the end of the search string) is the performance heavy part. Is the wildcard at the start of the string necessary? If so: You might have to consider pre-processing the data in a different way so that the search can use a single wildcard or no wildcard at all. This last part (depending on the data) is for example done by splitting the string by a delimiter and storing the data in separate rows, after which a much faster comparison and indexes are possible to be used.

To put data in multiple rows, we would assume a usable separator (can be multiple, the code just gets longer):

```
CREATE TABLE baseinfo (id INT NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  some other columns);

CREATE TABLE explodedstring(id INT NOT NULL, str VARCHAR(200),
   FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES baseinfo(id));

CREATE PROCEDURE explodestring(id int, fullstr VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
  {many examples exist already how to do this on SO}
END;
```

The procedure would take as input your key from the original data (`id` in this case), and the original string.
The output of the procedure would end up in a secondary table `explodedstring` against which you now could run a normal select (add some index for performance). The resulting `id`s would tell you which record would match.

Comment: Thanks for your lightning-speed answer! Putting the data in separate rows is not possible because I don't have a specific limit to the number of strings I need. Can I split the strings by a delimiter without using multiple rows or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: See update on the answer (in a few moments) to see how the multiple rows method could work